# Is it possible to have jQuery throw an exception when an element isn't found?

Tags: jquery, exception, undefined

I'm new to jQuery and I'd like to simplify the handling of elements it can't find, which is a fairly common problem. The following code shows what I mean:

```
var category = $('select#Category');
```

Now, I can inspect the returned variable to see if it wasn't found, but I'd definitely prefer an exception being thrown automatically in this case. Is this at all possible with jQuery? If not, is there some common idiom for implementing such automatic error checking on top of jQuery?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure of any existing functionality to do that, but I think this should work for you if you put it at the top of the page before using jQuery, but after loading it:

```
(function(){
    var _$ = $;
    $ = function(){
        var $res = _$.apply(0, arguments);
        if(!$res.length && typeof arguments[0] === 'string')
            throw 'No element Found: ' + arguments[0];
        return $res;
    }
    $ = _$.extend(true, $, _$);
})();
```

[***JSFiddle Example***](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/P87Cp/)

Comment: Improvement: change the throw line to `throw 'No Element Found: ' + arguments[0];` and you can see what selector caused the error.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, that's a nice addition :)

Comment: Actually, I see a real problem with this solution now. After replacing $ with this function, I must access the jQuery API as _$. For instance: _$.format. How about we change the solution to expose the exception-throwing wrapper as _$ instead? If I can't wrap $ completely, I'd rather just call _$() instead for checking for undefined variables.

Comment: @aknuds I fixed it so that `$` is wrapped completely now. Of course there are still shortcomings to this like `$('#elthatexists').filter('.classthatdoesnt')` won't throw any exceptions but will be empty

Comment: @Paul Can you check your fiddle?  I think it might be busted.

Answer (score 2):

I simply use this approach:

```
if (category.length == 1) {
// node has been found (and is the only one in the dom)
}
```

I think that throwing an exception is not a good idea :P

Comment: Maybe you're right on the whole about exceptions in JavaScript, but I hate having to explicitly check every variable. It's like in C, where I'd define macros for handling error indicating return values automatically.

Comment: @aknuds1 daveoncode is correct. Uncaught exceptions are errors in Javascript and cause execution to stop. So you'd need to have `try catch` blocks all over the place if you used exceptions. I updated my JSFIddle example to show how a line of code is never reached after an uncaught exception: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/P87Cp/

Comment: @PaulPRO This is no different from other languages though. The benefit is I can handle all undefined variables within one function in one place (the catch block).